# Why are all of my Airflow dags one run behind?

Tags: etl, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm setting up Airflow right now and loving it, except for the fact that my dags are perpetually running behind. See the picture below - this was taken on 2/19 at 15:50 UTC, and you can see that for each of the dags, they should have run exactly one more time between the last time they ran and the present time (there are a couple for which this is not true - those ones are currently turned off). Is there some piece of configuration I missed?

[image: my dags!]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

False alarm! Airflow just labels execution times differently than how I expected. Turns out an hourly job that runs at 15:00 is labels "14:00" and includes data up to 14:00+1:00.

From https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html:

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.
>
> **Let’s Repeat That** The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Comment: I noticed this as well. I have this job scheduled to run 8AM in the morning daily. My execution time is always one day lagged. Is this the correct behavior according to what you have noted here?

Comment: Yeah the execution date can be misleading. Best thing is to check the result and see if includes data in the date range you intend for it.

Answer (score 0):

Execution time is the lower bound of the batch.

Ex:
Say your execution schedule is hourly and its the run corresponding to the 13:00 schedule.
Your execution_time will be 12:00.
This is because we usually run the batch for 12:00 - 13:00 at 13:00(after the data is available for the batch).

But in my experience, we sometimes use the schedule based on the time its scheduled for(because we want the schedule to start and there are checks inside of the DAG/job that verify data readiness). In those cases, I just end up using next_execution_time(13:00) instead of execution_time(12:00).